# Extension method doesn't throw exception as expected

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods, mstest

[I have the following extension methods](https://github.com/tallesl/DataTableToObject/blob/c983dbf52b4e22635f1a3e5a5e0110e7ab978ce9/DataTableToObject/DataTableExtensions.cs):

```
public static T ToObject<T>(this DataRow row) where T : new()
{
    if (row == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("row");

    // do something
}

public static IEnumerable<T> ToObject<T>(this DataTable table) where T : new()
{
    if (table == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("table");

    // do something
}
```

And the respective tests:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
public void NullDataRow()
{
    // Arrange
    DataRow row = null;

    // Act
    row.ToObject<SomeData>();
}

[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
public void NullDataTable()
{
    // Arrange
    DataTable table = null;

    // Act
    table.ToObject<SomeData>();
}
```

The [DataRow test](https://github.com/tallesl/DataTableToObject/blob/c983dbf52b4e22635f1a3e5a5e0110e7ab978ce9/Tests/Tests.cs#L112-L121) passes (it throws `ArgumentNullException` normally) while the [DataTable one](https://github.com/tallesl/DataTableToObject/blob/c983dbf52b4e22635f1a3e5a5e0110e7ab978ce9/Tests/Tests.cs#L123-L132) doesn't (doesn't hit method nor throw anything).

I have absolutely no idea why the DataTable test isn't working (and the DataRow one is normal!).

(at first I thought it was a bug in my Visual Studio, but [the CI service that I use accused the same](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/TallesL/datatabletoobject/build/1.0.8))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll assume the `IEnumerable<T>` isn't just for fun, and that the extension method is actually an iterator.

Such iterator, doesn't actually execute to the point of throwing the exception until you start iterating it.

Comment: Damn, that makes all the sense. I totally forgot about deferred execution. Be right back.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted here is not enough to diagnose the problem, because it's caused by what's hidden behind `/// do something` comment. Looking at the code on github:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ToObject<T>(this DataTable table) where T : new()
{
    if (table == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("table");
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows) yield return ToObject<T>(row, false);
}
```

Having `yield return` there makes the method not actually execute any code until results are necessary (iteration is performed).

To make it work follow the same pattern .NET team uses in LINQ implementation:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int, TResult> selector) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    if (selector == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("selector");
    return SelectIterator<TSource, TResult>(source, selector);
}
```

where `SelectIterator` uses `yield return` to return one item at a time.